# Test Cassandras R + W > N

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I want to explicitly show the `R + W > N` rule at a presentation.

So my initial idea how to do this is as following:

```
// setup
1: Create a Docker network with 3 Cassandra Nodes.  
2: Create a simple Keyspace with Replication-Factor of 3.  
3: Explicitly shutdown two of the docker nodes.

4: Create a write query inserting some data with W=1
   As two of the nodes are down but one is still online this should succeed

5: Bring both of the nodes back online
6: Reading the Data I just pushed to one node with R=1
```

If I understand `R + W > N` correctly I should now have the chance of 2/3 to get inconsistent data. Which is exactly what I want to show.

**My Question is:

Is there an option I need to disable in order to stop nodes from syncing when they get back online?**

So I would require to disable these options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable hints on all nodes (set `hinted_handoff_enabled` in `cassandra.yaml` to `false`) - in this case, replication will happen only when you explicitly do the `nodetool repair`.

You also need to make sure that `read_repair_chance` and `dclocal_read_repair_chance` are set to 0 for a table where you'll do the test. The easiest way is just to specify these options when creating the table:

```
create table (

....)
WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0 and dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0;
```

Comment: So besides the `read repair` and `hinted handoff` there is no cyclic sync between nodes in cassandra ?

Thats something I actually asked myself. Because to me it seems that read repair and hinted_handoff is enough to become consistent after time.

Comment: No automatic... it’s why nodetool repair exist

Comment: Just checked everthing and it works :)
Thanks a lot !